# Is it possible to read the value of a switch in another active circuit?

Tags: arduino, switches, solenoid, input

I have a magnetic lock with an integrated switch (NC when locked). The lock opens when supplied current and stays open even after the current is no longer supplied (until someone manually closes the lock).
Since I don't want to burn out the coil I thought I'd use the integrated NC switch (right) to stop the current flow as soon as the lock opens.

I'm using Arduino to control the relay (left) to unlock the lock.
But I want the Arduino to get feedback on whether or not the lock opened but I don't know if/how I can use the integrated switch. The main problem is that if the relay (left) is open I can't measure the solenoid's switch state.
[image]

I left out diodes and 12v/5v stuff from the schema that I thought are irrelevant.

Comment: ou don't need to worry about burning out relay coils. That's not a thing. But you might burn out your D3 pin by trying to directly power a relay coil from it. Look up the right circuit for controlling a relay from an Arduino, you need an extra transistor and a diode.

Comment: It's not a relay, it is a 12V 2A solenoid and shouldn't be powered on for more than milliseconds at a time. I do have diodes and the relay block (left) has a built-in diode and transistor. I didn't include them in the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the solenoid switch control the current to its own coil, just hook up the solenoid switch to a digital input pin on the Arduino and have it check the state before allowing the relay coil to get power.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that. But I was concerned (perhaps unnecessarily) about the Arduino or code malfunctioning and burning out the solenoid. But this seems like the most reasonable way and I'll proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had the right idea, but you can make it work by connecting the unlocking relay to the *other* side of the switch, so that the relay only receives power when the switch is closed, otherwise it's disconnected. And then we can send that power to the Arduino pin instead, so you can detect it. No matter how much you screw up your Arduino code, it can't unlock the lock when it's already unlocked, because that relay doesn't get power.

If the magnetic lock is open, it sends power to the Arduino pin so you can sense it. If it's closed, it sends power to the relay which allows it to be opened. There's no way to open it while it's already open, because that relay doesn't get power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgHLT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact, you don't need an extra relay to implement this idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZp7eU.png)</sup>

Note that in both cases, if your relay voltage is higher than 5V, you'll need to reduce the voltage for the Arduino input to avoid damaging the Arduino.